# UIimageView array of images fade from one image to the next bug

Tags: ios, uiimageview, core-animation, nstimer, nsrunloop

Hi I have some code that mostly works. It basically animates, with a fade affect, number of images from an array.

Basically it all works well however I have a **slight bug** that when the view first loads **the first image only** in the array seems to rotate 90 degrees to the correct position and then fades to the same image but its annoying to see animate like this. All the fading from image to another is perfect just with the above mentioned bug. And as mentioned is **just on first load**.

Here is the code. `images` is an `MutableArray` and both `topImageView` and `bottomImageView` both are **ivars** and ** synthesized**. So is the `images` array, too.

```
int topIndex = 0, bottomIndex = 1;
-(void)imageFader{

self.imageViewBottom = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 370)];
[self.view addSubview:imageViewBottom];
[imageViewBottom setAlpha:0.0];
[imageViewBottom release];

self.imageViewTop = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 370)];
[self.view addSubview:imageViewTop];
[imageViewTop setAlpha:1.0];
[imageViewTop release];


    [imageViewTop setImage:[images objectAtIndex:topIndex]];


    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                             target:self 
                                           selector:@selector(onTimer) 
                                           userInfo:nil 
                                            repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [timer fire];


}

-(void)onTimer{

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{

            //set the image of the image that is not currently visible

    if (imageViewTop.alpha == 0) {
        [imageViewTop setImage:[images objectAtIndex:topIndex]];

    }
    if (imageViewBottom.alpha == 0) {
        [imageViewBottom setImage:[images objectAtIndex:bottomIndex]];

    }

    //make sure the images rotate
    [imageViewTop setAlpha:imageViewTop.alpha == 0 ? 1 : 0];
    [imageViewBottom setAlpha:imageViewBottom.alpha == 0 ? 1 : 0];

    //make sure the images play in a loop

    topIndex = topIndex < [images count]-1 ? bottomIndex+1 : 0;
    bottomIndex = bottomIndex < [images count]-1 ? bottomIndex+1 : 0;}];



}
```

And here is how the images are saved to the docs directory before being loaded in to the `MutableArray` for the animation.

```
    -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; 
        NSMutableDictionary *metadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        //Save to camera roll       
        [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation) ALAssetOrientationRight completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) { NSLog(@"completionBlock");

        }];


        int imageNumber = 0;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *pathToFile;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


        do
        {
            // increment the image
            imageNumber++;

            // get the new path to the file
            pathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"standingImage%d.JPG", imageNumber]];
        }
        while([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathToFile]);
        /* so, we loop for as long as we keep coming up with names that already exist */

        UIImage *image2 = image; // imageView is my image from camera

        //Use UIImageJPEGRepresentation to maitain image orientation!
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.9);
        [imageData writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:NO];



        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Where are you loading the actual images from? Are these PNGs in your bundle? Please add relevant code that does this.

Comment: @stavash Hi Sorry I should have mentioned these images are saved from the imagePicker (Camera) to the documents directory and the images are being saved as JPGS to preserve the correct orientation at the time the images are taken. They are then loaded from the docs directory and added to the mutable array called images as mentioned above.

Comment: Anyone have an idea whats happening with the one image?

Answer (score 0):

This unexpected orientation may be caused by the origin of the images - the UIImagePickerController. Try accessing the JPEG files you mentioned in your comment and check their orientation, then you'll at least narrow down the potential cause of your issue.

Comment: thanks for your answer stavash as a test I have tried some other images from the app bundle and it still does this. Whats interesting is if I swap this line [imageViewTop setImage:[images objectAtIndex:topIndex]]; for [imageViewBottom setImage:[images objectAtIndex:topIndex]]; then the other image is rotated.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. What about defining these image views in Interface Builder? That way you'll be able to make sure they are properly configured and positioned.